# How to get mails sent via Network.Mail.Mime classified not as junk?

Tags: email, haskell, gmail, sendmail, spam

I use lib Network.Mail.Mime to send emails from my Haskell program. I reckon it uses postfix to send the emails. When I try to send mails to my gmail address I do receive them, only they are in the junk, and this happens whatever I fill the "form" fill with.
How can I avoid this behavior?
Thx

Comment: According to the docs it uses sendmail http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-mail-0.3.0

Answer (score 5):

The mime-mail interface will send email, via sendmail, using the simple api:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text
import Network.Mail.Mime

main = do
    simpleMail
        "you@example.com"
        "me@example.com"
        "Test"
        "This is a test"
        ""
        []
```

assuming you're correctly using `Data.Text` to avoid locale encoding issues.

Now, this is likely to set insufficient headers, so the spam filter will hit it. You may need to ask gmail to *not* classify this as spam, or alternatively you could set more headers so it doesn't look like fake email.

Comment: Indeed.Already tried to have gmail mark it as "not junk" but the next mail will still go to the junk :/ How should I know what to put in my headers to have gmail recognize it?

Answer (score 3):

Don is right about sendmail and the headers issue. But mail headers alone often aren't enough to prevent mail being marked as spam. It can be related to your ip range being blacklisted, or any number of other things not explicitly tied to the method by which you send mail. The first step is to check how mail from the box you're using is marked in general, and depending on the situation, to configure sendmail to forward through an authorized connection to a trusted mail agent, etc.

Comment: If it's the headers that are wrong, can I modify them with the Mail.Mime library (I recall I saw smth related to headers in the library), but how can I know what to put in there? Plus, will the headers have to be specific to Gmail or will they be valid to others? Because I intend to send the emails to addresses that are not Gmail too (and I checked, they *are* marked as junk too). The other solution: configuring sendmail (or postfix here) to forward through an authorized connection seems to be a good solution, I have been looking for how-to to do that, but nothing seems very explicit to me.

Answer (score 0):

Like sclv mentioned already, it can be caused by many issues.

I just went through a similar ordeal, and spamassassin was a great help. All my incoming email is ran through SpamAssassin which leaves information in headers about the heuristics it used, or rather which heuristics failed. If you're sending HTML-mail, make sure you have similar enough plain content, and that you have a proper sender etc.

I sent a similar mail as Don Stewart to myself and these are the spamassassin headers:

```
X-Spam-Status: No, score=1.1 required=5.0
        tests=BAYES_00,DKIM_ADSP_CUSTOM_MED,
        FREEMAIL_FROM,NML_ADSP_CUSTOM_MED,RCVD_IN_RP_RNBL,RFC_ABUSE_POST
,SPF_NEUTRAL,
        T_TO_NO_BRKTS_FREEMAIL autolearn=no version=3.3.2-r929478
```

Probably not all of them apply to your case, but it might give some hint. Try googling those heuristics.